# Optimize complicated query

Tags: c#, t-sql, query-optimization

I have a query that merge table by some id.

```sql
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PagedOptionData1.ExternalId ASC,
                                   PagedOptionData1.RunDateTime DESC
                          ) AS RowNumber,
       PagedOptionData1.*,
       PagedOptionData2.*
FROM   PagedOptionData AS PagedOptionData1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN PagedOptionData AS PagedOptionData2
         ON PagedOptionData1.ExternalId = PagedOptionData2.ExternalId
            AND PagedOptionData2.rn = 2
WHERE  PagedOptionData1.rn = 1
```

Where PagedOptionData is a temp table with various join .

Can this query can be optimized ?

Comment: First order of the day, does it need to be optimized?  Why is it too slow for you?  How long does it take to execute and is it causing you problems?  First thing I noted is that you use `*`.  Do you need to select *every* column?  If not, specify the ones you want explicitly.

Comment: Change topic to: "SQL 101: optimize trivial query". if that is complicated, your brain likely explodes the first time you see a complicated 4 printed pages query.

Comment: What do you mean by the phrase `Where PagedOptionData is a temp table with various join .`. That doesn't seem to make sense. Is `PagedOptionData` defined as a common table expression? If so show the definition for that.

Answer (score 4):

You need an index on `(ExternalId ASC, RunDateTime DESC)` whether you use your original form or my suggestion

One thing stands out: how will you remove ambiguity in column names when you use SELECT * twice on the same table?

To avoid ordinal column access and simplify the query, I'd consider re-writing:

```
SELECT TOP 2
   *
FROM
   PagedOptionData
ORDER BY
   ExternalId ASC, RunDateTime DESC
```

This simplifies matters considerably at the expense of more logic in the client code

Answer (score 2):

The query doesn't look very complicated, so if it is running slow the optimization should be done by adding indexes. Sql Server can suggest indexes to add.

1. Paste the query into a new Sql Management Studio Window.
2. Click the "Include Actual Execution Plan" button in the toolbar.
3. Run the query.
4. Check the returned Execution plan for an index suggestion (shown in green text right below the query).
5. Create the index and retry.